# Jekyll server not running from shell script: Could not find i18n-0.7.0 in any of the sources

Tags: shell, jekyll

If I type
    bundle exec jekyll serve

into the Ubuntu terminal, it launches the jekyll server fine. If however I put it into a shell script:

```
#! /bin/bash

cd /home/xxx/Documents/github/xxx
bundle exec jekyll serve
$SHELL
```

It gives the error:

```
Could not find i18n-0.7.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Following the instructions given there does not solve it either. And I have tried inserting a pause after the cd command as well as launching the script from the right folder to start with, none of which works (i.e. it is not a due to not cd'ing in time)
Any ideas?

Comment: Are you running the script with the same user as you do manually? Try to add `bundle install`into the script :)

Comment: Yes I am , and no that does not work either.